# ElasticSearch 2.0 upgrade now can't connect to server

Tags: elasticsearch

I've had an elastic server cluster running for a few months now.   2 node cluster.  Pretty simple, things were working pretty nice.

So, I upgraded from 1.7.2 to 2.0.0 today and now I can't get to my servers.... If I curl on the server using local host, everything works fine, if I curl on the machine using it's machine name, I get connection refused.

Upgrading is the only thing that's changed.   Any ideas why elastic isn't seeing anything when I use the machine name?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 11):

FWIW you can set the `network.host: 0.0.0.0` in `elasticsearch.yml` or launch as 
follows : `bin/elasticsearch --network.host 0.0.0.0`

This way you should be able to access the cluster in `loopback` as well as `non_loopback`

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_network_changes.html) is, probably, the change in 2.0 that made the cluster accessible only via `localhost`.

Update each `elasticsearch.yml` file and provide a `network.host` for the node.

Comment: Thanks.   That's what did it.  Guess that's what I get when I didn't overwrite the current elastic search.yml file. :)

Comment: Well, had to play with it a bit more, it kept wanting to bind to my local address.   Ending up getting the _non_loopback_ version to work, kinda anyways, I can hit it from external machines via hostname, but I have to use the IP address on the box.  Not a big deal for me really.   Not I can rebuild it's twin, which I proceeded to trash tonight.