# Cannot access Elasticsearch 2.0 in Vagrant VM from host OS

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, vagrant, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm trying to get Elasticsearch 2.0 up and running in a Vagrant VM. The method I was using for 1.7 no longer works, so I'm trying to update my method. I can get ES 2.0 installed in the VM, and it seems to work fine from within the VM, but I can't access it from outside the VM. It's like the VM isn't port-forwarding port 9200 for some reason, even though I'm telling it to. So I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Given this `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.hostname = "ES-2.0.0"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 9200, guest: 9200
  config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/sloan/code", "/srv/code"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 1
    v.name = config.vm.hostname.to_s
  end

end
```

my old `bootstrap.sh` works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

# install openjdk-7 
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jdk

# install curl
sudo apt-get -y install curl

# install Elasticsearch 1.7.3
wget https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.7.3.tar.gz -O elasticsearch.tar.gz
tar -xf elasticsearch.tar.gz
rm elasticsearch.tar.gz
sudo mv elasticsearch-* elasticsearch
sudo mv elasticsearch /usr/local/share

# set up ES as service
curl -L http://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-servicewrapper/tarball/master | tar -xz
sudo mv *servicewrapper*/service /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/
rm -Rf *servicewrapper*
sudo /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch install
sudo ln -s 'readlink -f /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch' /usr/local/bin/rcelasticsearch

# start ES service
sudo service elasticsearch start

# enable cors (to be able to use Sense)
sudo echo "http.cors.enabled: true" >> /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
# enable dynamic scripting
sudo echo "script.disable_dynamic: false" >> /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

I mean that it works in the sense that, from the host OS (OS X 10.9.5) I can curl ES just fine:

```
es173 > curl localhost:9200
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Gibbon",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.3",
    "build_hash" : "05d4530971ef0ea46d0f4fa6ee64dbc8df659682",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-10-15T09:14:17Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But when I use this new version of `bootstrap.sh` which I cooked up by trying to follow the Elasticsearch documents (always an arduous task):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

# install curl
sudo apt-get -y install curl

# install openjdk-7 
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jdk

wget -qO - https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/2.x/debian stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch-2.x.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch

sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start

# enable cors (to be able to use Sense)
sudo echo "http.cors.enabled: true" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
# enable dynamic scripting
sudo echo "script.disable_dynamic: false" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart
```

does NOT work. From inside the VM, `curl localhost:9200` works as expected, but from the host OS I get:

```
es200 > curl localhost:9200
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

What am I missing here? Can anybody tell me why isn't the new version port forwarding?

Comment: I don't know how the ES network specific configuration is in your setup, but that would be the first I'd look at. Because there is a big change in 2.0 mentioned in the documentation, meaning this: `Currently an elasticsearch node may be bound to multiple addresses, but only publishes one.` This wasn't like that before. One way of doing the same in 2.0 seems to be to set `network.bind_host: 0`.

Comment: Does that go in `elasticsearch.yml`? I tried it, doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: How do I find out what the "ES network specific configuration" is in my setup? Other than adding two (now three) settings to `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`, I haven't changed the default settings in any way.

Comment: try `network.host: 0.0.0.0` as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403363/elasticsearch-2-0-upgrade-now-cant-connect-to-server/33438428#33438428)

Comment: Whoops, I had another problem (`script.disable_dynamic: false`), and once I fixed that, either of your answers work. So thanks to you both!

Comment: Still having trouble with cors, though. I'm using [this code](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_setting_changes.html#_jsonp_support) below, but I still can't hit ES from local javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Upon examining the ES log file (`cat /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log`) I found that `script.disable_dynamic: false` was breaking things:

```
[2015-10-31 19:58:54,428][INFO ][node                     ] [Yuri Topolov] version[2.0.0], pid[9826], build[de54438/2015-10-22T08:09:48Z]
[2015-10-31 19:58:54,428][INFO ][node                     ] [Yuri Topolov] initializing ...
[2015-10-31 19:58:54,537][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Yuri Topolov] loaded [], sites []
[2015-10-31 19:58:54,630][INFO ][env                      ] [Yuri Topolov] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/mapper/precise64-root)]], net usable_space [72.3gb], net total_space [78.8gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2015-10-31 19:58:58,668][ERROR][bootstrap                ] Guice Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: script.disable_dynamic is not a supported setting, replace with fine-grained script settings.
Dynamic scripts can be enabled for all languages and all operations by replacing `script.disable_dynamic: false` with `script.inline: on` and `script.indexed: on` in elasticsearch.yml
    at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.<init>(ScriptService.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at <<<guice>>>
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:198)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
```

I added that setting after I had my problem, but before I initially tried the suggestions in the comments, and so ES was failing. Fixing this setting didn't fix my original problem, but it was obscuring the solution.

Anyway, here is the `bootstrap.sh` file that is working for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

# install curl
sudo apt-get -y install curl

# install openjdk-7 
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jdk

# install ES
wget -qO - https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/2.x/debian stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch-2.x.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10

# either of the next two lines is needed to be able to access "localhost:9200" from the host os
sudo echo "network.bind_host: 0" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
sudo echo "network.host: 0.0.0.0" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

# enable cors (to be able to use Sense)
sudo echo "http.cors.enabled: true" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
sudo echo "http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

# enable dynamic scripting
sudo echo "script.inline: on" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
sudo echo "script.indexed: on" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

Comment: probably could enable all domains and see  `http.cors.allow-origin:/https?:\/\/.*/`

Answer (score 12):

In your `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` configuration file set `network.host: 0.0.0.0` so that `elasticsearch` is accessible outside of `localhost`. Remember to do a `service elasticsearch restart`.

Comment: Restart Elasticsearch with `systemd` by `sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch.service`.